# Fourier Series coefficients of the integral

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I was solving an exercise and was stuck on the following problem:

I am given a periodic, continuous function $f(t)$ and I know that it has a fourier series representation of
$$f(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n e^{j\frac{2\pi}{T}nt}$$
for a sequence $\{a_n\}$, where $T$ is the period of $f(t)$.
I am asked to find the fourier series coefficients of a function $g(t)$, where
$$g(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t f(x)dx$$

My first question arises here: How can I know if the expression provided for $g(t)$ converges? Do I have to accept something for simplicity?

Not caring about this and reading more, I see that the problem also states that I can assume   that the average value of $f(t)$ is $0$.
By this, I think they meant something that simplifies everything nicely, but I understand the following:
$$\int_a^{a+T}f(x)dx = 0, \forall a\in\mathbb{R}$$
I still did not think that this assumption solved any issues, but it helps me see that the period of $g(t)$ must also be $T$.

I went on with writing the analysis formula. But everything I obtained seems senseless to me, so as the issue I had at the beginning of the question. What am I missing?

P.S. I am new to this topic and area, so please provide extra information for your notation or if you see that I don't know something. Thank you!

Comment: How do you justify changing $t$ to $T$ in the integral over $x$ when you change the order of integration? Perhaps evaluating a specific example such as $f(t)=\sin\left(t-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ will provide some insight.

Comment: I don't believe the integral $g(t)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^t f(x)\,dx$ even converges when $f(t)$ is a periodic function (unless $f(t)=0$), so how does this question make sense? Letting $g(t)=\int f(t)\,dt$ makes more sense to me.

Comment: @steven-clark How would you solve it in that case? I think I made a mistake while considering the area I am taking the integral in, btw. You are right.

Comment: I believe you can derive the term of the Fourier series for $g(t)=\int f(t)\,dt$ from the term-wise indefinite integral $\int a(n)\, e^{j \frac{2 \pi}{T} n t} \, dt=-a(n) \frac{T}{2 \pi} \frac{j}{n}\, e^{j \frac{2 \pi}{T} n t}$ of the Fourier series of $f(t)$.

Comment: This seem to work for $f(t)=\sin\left(t-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)$ where the Fourier series is $f(t)=\frac{1}{2} (-1)^{3/4}\, e^{-i t}-\frac{1}{2} (-1)^{1/4}\, e^{i t}$ and where $g(t)=\int \sin\left(t-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\,dt=-\frac{\sin(t)+\cos(t)}{\sqrt{2}}$ since $\int \left(\frac{1}{2} (-1)^{3/4} e^{-i t}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt[4]{-1} e^{i t}\right) \, dt=\frac{1}{2} (-1)^{3/4} e^{i t}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt[4]{-1} e^{-i t}=-\frac{\sin (t)+\cos (t)}{\sqrt{2}}$.